# How to approach event sourcing with millions of records

Tags: event-sourcing

We're looking at implementing event sourcing / CQRS and for 95% of our system I can reason about the events and it doesn't scare me.

On the other hand, we also have a requirement where customers can insert data for millions of records in one go. A large portion of them can be updated in one go as they move location etc or have batch level details updated. It also needs to be reversed if they change their mind moments after.

Each record relates to a physical entity in the real world and it's important that the read model is updated quickly and the audit trail preserved at all costs for each record.

I can't seem to find any advice on how to handle these volumes. Are you supposed to write an event for every single record and action and just accept that it's going to be computationally / Database expensive?  Are there any case studies that have similar requirements?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Are you supposed to write an event for every single record and action and just accept that it's going to be computationally / Database expensive?

A potentially helpful heuristic -- how would you do it with a version control system?  Would you create an empty document, and then introduce a million commits, or would you have a single `Data Imported` commit, and go from there?

An important consideration to notice is that the authority for the data is *somewhere else*.  "Physical entities in the real world" are not subject to the rules of your domain model; you you have there is a big pile of *reference data*.

It can help to think in processes -- what you have is an import reference data process, that has a relatively small number of immediate steps, and independently some "do interesting things with each record" which may turn out to be millions of little processes with some small number of events.

Comment: Although the "source of truth" is out in the real world, i need to be able to look at the history of events for a particular item (until they're out of our jurisdiction) in a timely manner.  I considered having one event for a large batch operations but then it would be difficult to tie these to individual items when I came to get the event history